# Flutter dio error SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the last flutter version on a fresh created project. I'm trying to call this URL https://crmdemo.fortex.com/open/public/login

But on iOS or Android I get flutter: Error SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = crmdemo.fortex.com, port = 49266

Response response = await _dio.request(
url,
data: data,
queryParameters: queryParameters,
options: _checkOptions(method, options),
cancelToken: cancelToken,
);

RequestMethod: POST

RequestHeaders:{content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8, os: iOS 16.2, appVersion: 1.0.0, app_sys: 2}

Is there anything to do more than this ? I check the Android manifest and it has the Internet permission so should be ok

Dio: 4.0.6